# Learning with Movies

Tags: english-to-german

For learning German, is it better to see a German movie with English subtitles or an English movie with German subtitles?

Comment: As a kid, I learned a lot of German and English (and some French) by seeing original movies and TV series with Dutch subtitles (I'm Dutch). Especially the pronunciation comes out better that way. YMMV. But this question might be off-topic here.

Comment: I see 3 votes to close as opinion based. Well, my answer is of course my opinion, but I think I have a strong argument to justify my opinion, so leave it open, voters.

Comment: You can have a look at https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/ to see whether you think that your question would fit there.

Comment: You should be aware that the subtitles are often wrong. That often drives me crazy when watching movies with subtitles because I can't help reading them and comparing the translation to the original

Answer (score 3):

Both German audio and German subtitles.

But I recommend watching German news instead of movies as they have more text per time and you can hardly figure out what they are about without understanding the language. You can watch a German movie with German subtitles afterwards, to cool off.

I also recommend the *Mediatheken* (there are several) of the [German public TV broadcasters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_in_Germany#Public_broadcasters). Just search for the broadcaster name and *Mediathek*. You can watch selected German television programmes (news, shows, movies) and they often have *superb* subtitles, who are intended for deaf persons but come in casually for language learners, too.

Comment: But news provide examples of a very specific type of language that does not necessarily match normal usage by native speakers (even less so than movies). When thinking of news, expressions such as "mutmaßlicher Täter" or "warf ... Maßlosigkeit vor" come to mind, which may be precise and formally correct, but which have hardly any place in German outside of news reports.

Comment: As for Mediatheken, I am not sure these are always accessible outside of Germany; their content might be subject to geoblocking (due to region-specific broadcasting licenses owned by the channels).

Comment: The interesting – subtitled – programmes are own productions and not so likely to be blocked outside Germany.

Comment: As a Deutschlerner myself, I can testify that listening to the news gets very boring after a few days. Also, the use of the language is actually not very wide, and may start repeating itself.

Comment: Boring is good for drill.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to see a German movie with English subtitles.

Reading subtitles is a bit stressing, and a interesting plot, which you understand by heart, because it is in English, might easily distract you from reading the subtitles at all.

The opposite way, you will always feel the need to watch what has been said, if you don't understand it.

From my YouTube experience, I can agree with Janka, that even German films with German subtitles might be of help. Sometimes, I don't understand English spoken words, but when I see them written, I can. In case of YT, I can even pause the lecture and look a word up.

Comment: IMHO best is English language movie (that you already know and like) dubbed into German. Then, for a couple of times watch it with English subtitles to help you with the extra vocab to get most of it. Then ideally you would move to German audio and German subtitles BUT (and this is SO annoying) most movies have completely different translations. I am not talking about where they need to compress something when someone is speaking very fast, but for **** everything. Still I find this fun. Notting Hügel anyone? (This wd have been an answer if the **** hadn't closed this!)